# String Replace With GSUTIL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sed, gsutil

I am trying to remove a pipe at the end of the header(first) row in a .csv file in GCS using GSUTIL and sed.  The command below produces the output `sed: can't read ... No such file or directory`

```
sed 's/58_rxsig"|"/58_rxsig1/' gs://../file.csv
```

58_rxsig is the last field name in the header row so my thought was to find the literal string '58_rxsig|' and just replace with the literal string '58_rxsig' but I've apparently been unable to get the syntax correct.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Sample Input:

```
12_word|
```

Desired Output:

```
12_word
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sample input and desired output added

Comment: `sed 's/|$//' file`?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" sed  's/|$//' FILE

produced the output...

'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sed` command doesn't know how to read files from GCS.  You'll need to download the contents of your file from GCS to a local file and then supply that as your last argument to `sed`, e.g. if you had an object named "a/b/c.txt" in your bucket:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/a/b/c.txt my/local/directory/
sed <your flags and arguments here> my/local/directory/c.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `gsutil cat` and redirect the stream to the `sed` command with the pipe.

```
gsutil cat gs://<bucket>/<blob> | sed <flags & arguments>
```